# How do I import a CSV file in Google My Maps?

Tags: python, qgis

I am trying to import a CSV into My Maps, but the import fails and the following message is displayed:

> Failed import. Columns name cannot contain more than 64 characters nor the following elements : '<>`{}|.

But none of these characters are included in my columns name.

Is there a certain number of maximum columns in My Maps or am I not aware of certain constraints?

So after response from mkrieger1 :

[Here is the cropped file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfewT.png)

[I get the following message, indicating that the import is successful but that My Maps has collided the columns, which is undesirable since I wanted my columns to be separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQyd9.png)

Comment: Can you show a minimal example CSV file that gives this error?

Comment: Hi ! Sorry, I did not know how to share a file on a post, but I used FileDropper instead : http://www.filedropper.com/puitsintertv220210615

Comment: Can you try to create the *smallest possible* file that gives the error (start with an empty file)? How small can you get? You should be able to just copy and paste the file contents into the post.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include it.